# can we add item in tree view (without before select) jstree without selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am make to make tree view using js tree plugin.I have to add item so I need to select item why ?

it is possible we can add without select ..if i press add it "1 " folder then 2 folder below...

http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/5/

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button>add</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the parent node to the `create_node` function.

```
$('#tree').create_node(parent_node, child_node);
```

Look here for details: [http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=create_node&f=create_node%28[obj,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded]%29](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=create_node&f=create_node%28%5bobj,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded%5d%29)

EDIT:
Made a fiddle to illustrate my thoughts. http://jsfiddle.net/6HTjK/11/
If no node is selected the new_node is created at the root level. If you have a node selected the new_node is created as a child of the selected node.

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you fiddle to make simple example

Comment: there can you please check my fiddle

Comment: Great answer ..But I have one question there is option od remand ..can we remove that?

Comment: can we add submenu also without selection ?

Comment: what do you mean whith "add submenu" and "option od remand"??

Comment: if I need to add inside "a" as a example I need to select "a" then press "add" .can we add with inside or submenu of "a" without selection

Comment: it is just the name of the new_node. You can use whatever you want for that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51969/discussion-between-user3530755-and-oerl)

Comment: Just added a new fiddle that should be what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/5FgEu/6/